# Ajuda no Login [Ruby On Rails - Gem Devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Estou utilizando a Gem Devise para a criação de um sistema de login. Entretanto, meu projeto requer 2 campos de verificação do login ao invés de apenas 1. Por exemplo, a empresa tem 5 departamentos, o usuário tem o código 0010 e trabalha no departamento 1, então para o login dele precisaria digitar o nome do departamento dele e o código dele (além, é claro, da sua senha de acesso).
Como faço para implementar 2 campos de verificação do login? Copiei o campo do código nas páginas do devise, mas ouvi falar que precisaria mexer no controller também. Isso procede? Como eu mexo no controller para atender a esse pedido?

Answer (score 2):

Para gerar o controller e alterar conforme o que você precisa, é necessário rodar este comando:

> Create your custom controllers using the generator which requires a scope:
>
> $ rails generate devise:controllers [scope]

Caso queira dar uma olhada na documentação: [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

Busque pela tag **Configuring controllers** caso queira mais informações.